# Fancybox - передача параметров

Tags: jquery, fancybox, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток, всем привет.

Вот какой день вожусь с **fancybox** и ни как не могу понять, как передать значения из модального окна на страницу откуда была вызвана форма.
Суть задачи в том что есть страница, на котором выбирается город. При клике на **выбрать город** сплывает модальное окно, где из списка нужно выбрать город поставив галочку(вариант может быть множественным), и далее имеется кнопка **выбрать**. При клике на кнопку выбрать - модальное окно должно скрыться и на странице вместо надписи **выбрать город**  - заменяется на город выбранный из списка.

На странице /index.php вызывается модальное окно, 
html:

```
 <div class="bl_categoty">
    <div class="choice_category">Выбрать город</div>
 <div>
```

вот js:

```
 $(".choice_category").fancybox({
        'padding':6,
        'href':'/modal/categories.php',
         // события при закрытии формы применяется.
         beforeClose: function(){
            console.log("форма закрыта");
            $(".bl_categoty .value_heading").empty().text("ГОРОД");
        }
 });
```

Модальное окно находиться в /modal/categories.php. На данной странице имеется список городов и кнопка **выбрать**.При клике на него необходимо чтобы данные передались на страницу /index.php и подставились в .choice_category. Код js страницы  /modal/categories.php ниже:

```
$(".action_category").click(function(event){
    // value_heading должно записаться выбранный город. - не применяется
    $(".bl_categoty .value_heading").empty().text("ГОРОД");
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); // событие срабатывает

    // не применяется
    $('.choice_category').fancybox({
        beforeClose: function(){
            console.log("*******************");
            $(".bl_categoty .value_heading").empty().text("ГОРОД");
        }
    });
});
```

Как мне передать параметры из модального окна на страницу /index.php

Заранее спасибо за ответ. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу

```
 $(".action_category").click(function(event){
      var category =  parent.document.getElementById("category_id");
      category.value="Medved"
      parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш ответ можно записать так:

```
parent.$('#category_id').val('Medved');
```

Comment: Добавьте описание, почему предложенный Вами вариант лучше. И мне кажется, Ваш код не будет работать (parent.$ не переваривается вроде бы)

Comment: Этот вариант на jQuery, в отличии от предложенного JS, и он работает)